# How to enable or disable the buttons in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

My Design has the following lines of code:

```
<Button  BorderThickness="0" Content="Done" FontSize="21.333" Height="65" Margin="334,13,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Name="btnConvert"  >
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/button_back2.png" />
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
```

My code goes `btnConvert.IsEnabled = false;`.

It can't disable the button. Instead, it hides the button. I need that button to be visible but disabled. Please help me.

Comment: How to  disable in some condition and need to enable that button in some condition .please help me isenable property hide the button .i don't need hide only disable....

Comment: i use IsEnabled to toggle whether a button is enabled or not. works just fine. How are you calling it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isenabled works for me. try your xaml code in some xaml viewer to check if you are not doing anything wrong

Answer (score 2):

This is what I usually do:

```
`btnConvert.IsHitTestVisible = false;`
```

It will disable the button, but you can see the button with the same colors at beginning.